java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with upgrading bcpro-jdk15 to bcpro-jdk18on issue
We have upgraded BouncyCastle jar and getting following error at runtime

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with upgrading bcpro-jdk15 to bcpro-jdk18on jar BouncyCastle jars. Org.bouncycastle.jcajce.JcaJceHelper.


That's the fault of another dependency. What others do you have?

Hi, thanks a lot for quick response.   We have bcpg-jdk15on and bcpro-jdk15on dependences are ther.....   If I remove bcpro-jdk15on dependency, then also getting error

I'm confused. I thought you said you'd updated to 18 so why is there 15 anything in there?

Sorry for confusing...  We have bcprov-jdk16 and bcprov-jdk15on are there in existing code....    Now I have replaced bcprov-jdk16 to bcprov-jdk18on .......  Kindly suggest is this correct

You need to get rid of anything that doesn't have 18 in it. Moreover (according to Maven) only bcprov-jdk18on  >= 1.74 is free of vulns

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What was the old version and what is the new version? (The 15 and 18 are not versions of Bounce Castle, but the target Java version, that is Java 5 and Java 8.) Some classes were moved to separate artifacts, so you may need to add additional BouncyCastle libraries.

Hi all, Previously we have 1). bcpg-jdk15on 1.4.7 which replaced to bcpg-jdk18on 1.74 version. 2). bcprov-jdk15on 1.47 is replaced to bcprov-jdk18on1.74. After this we are getting compiled error like : No suitable constructor found for PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(int, Secure random, Srting). Kindly advise the required lib to add.... Not able to find that in internet... thanks in advance
